# QGIS vs JOSM, described by example

Tags: qgis, josm

I am just getting started with the GIS world. For my learning exercise I'm thinking about making a map to show all US National Parks I have (not) visited. The map would display parks regardless of how zoomed out I am and be themed. It would color parks differently if I have visited one already. The map will show select airports and custom trip routes. Parks will be grouped by trip. Bonus points if I can do optimization analysis. The list of national parks grows each year, so dynamic updates would be nice. I don't really want to type all the parks in by hand as a learning exercise, if reasonably possible.

I don't know what tools to use. My programming skills are strong, but I am relatively new to GIS. I am eager to learn and don't want to use a simple WYSIWYG web editor unless that really is the best open source tool for the job. I don't know the **difference between QGIS or JOSM,** so I can't tell which tool I need to learn. I also don't know if there are **other tools** to consider. Viewing mediums will include browser, maybe OsmAnd on mobile, PDF, and a big physical engineering blueprint.

Comment: QGIS is great for making custom visual interpretations of truth sets. JOSM is good for editing the OSM truth set. Additional truth sets, like ArcGIS's Feature Services, can also be imported into QGIS for visual representation like Mapperz points out. OSM has this information too, though I don't know how one would do it. Once data is captured in QGIS, it can be exported for use in various mediums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention **QGIS**.

So use the ArcGIS Feature Service from NPS

```
https://services1.arcgis.com/fBc8EJBxQRMcHlei/ArcGIS/rest/services
```

[image]

Load into QGIS the NPS_PARK_BOUNDARIES
`https://services1.arcgis.com/fBc8EJBxQRMcHlei/ArcGIS/rest/services/NPS_Park_Boundaries/FeatureServer`

[image]

To add 'Visited' Right Click and Save As (Shapefile/Geopackage)

Then edit the shapefile and create a field 'Visited' (String/Text Field length 3) Calculate to equal 'No'
Then edit the individual National Parks that you have visited with a 'Yes'

Update with an example

[image]

Comment: How would I add my own annotations to this, like "visited"?

Comment: Right Click Save as (shapefile, geopackage) then load that into QGIS and you will be able to add a column visited and display with classification based on visited

Comment: updated with extra step to add visited field to a shapefile